# Expectation of Gaussian random varible composed with max function

Tags: calculus, probability, random-variables, normal-distribution, expectation

For $i\in [n]$ , $g_i \sim N(1,1)$ is a Gaussian random variable. We assum that all the $g_i$ are independent.

Consider  $u_i, x_i \in \mathbb{R}$

What is the best why to compute the expectation:

$$ E_g \big[ max\lbrace 0, \sum_{i=1}^n g_iu_ix_i\rbrace \big] =  E_g \big[ max\lbrace 0, \langle g \odot u , x \rangle \rbrace \big]$$

Where $u\odot g$ is the element-wise product.

Can I look on $max\lbrace 0, \sum_{i=1}^n g_iu_ix_i\rbrace$ as a truncated random variable?

Comment: In general, this can't be computed. One needs to know the *joint* distribution of $g_i$ (i.e. that they are independent).

Comment: yes, they are independent. will edit it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the $g_i$ are independent, then $\sum \limits_{i = 1}^n g_i u_i x_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ with $\mu = \sum \limits_{i = 1}g_i u_i$ and $\sigma^2 = \sum \limits_{i = 1}^n(g_iu_i)^2$. So if $N$ is a standard normal variable, then $\sum \limits_{i = 1}^n g_i u_i x_i \stackrel{d}{=}\sigma N + \mu$. Now we can calculate the expectation:

$$\begin{align*}
&\mathbb{E}[\max(0, \sigma N + \mu)] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int \max(0, \sigma x + \mu) e^{-x^2/2} \, dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\mu/\sigma}^{\infty} (\sigma x + \mu)e^{-x^2/2} \, dx \\
={}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \left(\mu \Psi(\mu/\sigma) +\sigma e^{-\mu^2/(2\sigma^2)}\right)
\end{align*}$$

Comment: psai is the cdf? how did you calculate the last equality? I mean, how did you expressed the last integral with the cdf ? 
thanks.

Comment: Psi is the CDF of a standard normal random variable. By symmetry we have $\int_{-a}^\infty \exp(-x^2/2) \, dx = \int_{-\infty}^a \exp(-x^2/2) \, dx$. Then you can apply the definition of the CDF.

Comment: I think it's a mistake, should be $ \mu(1 - \Phi(\frac{ - \mu}{\sigma}))$

Comment: By the aforementioned symmetry $1 - \Phi(-x) = \Phi(x)$.